# What happens to Felice at the end of Saga of the Exiles?

Tags: julian-may, saga-of-the-exiles

In Julian May's *Saga of the Exiles*, Felice merges with Culleket when her attack against Aiken/Marc fails. They become an "incandescent duality" that Elizabeth safeguards in Brede's "room without doors".

Does anything ever come of this? (e.g. in the later *Galactic Milieu* books). It always seemed to me that the story wasn't ended, but I don't recall anything obvious in the later novels. (I originally thought the "great carbuncle" was related, but that doesn't seem to fit).

Comment: There are a number of loose ends in Saga of the Pliocene Exiles. The Agraynel prophecy of Morna-Ia Kingmaker, the child of Nodonn and the quarter-firvulag woman and the Felice/Culluket duality. Just have to hope May brings out some more books I suppose.

Comment: That was my thought... May was leaving herself a little wiggle room for a possible sequel.... I liked the Felice character.....But she had assumed almost god-like powers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Julian May has herself said that the carbuncle is not the duality. (I don't have the source to hand I'm afraid.)

Felice/Cull never resurface in later novels, although it's lovely to speculate on whether they might be Fury whilst reading the earlier books in the Milieu Trilogy.  The resolution and motivation of who Fury is is a little mundane compared to the possibilities in my opinion (although emotionally more satisfying)

Answer (score 4):

As a friend and somewhat confidante of Julian May, I am privileged to have been able to discuss many of the questions posted on this forum.

Many, many years ago I speculated that Fury was actually the Culluket/Felice duality resurrected. Julian reminded me that only Elizabeth could enter the room without doors when she reprogrammed it to "imprison" the Culluket/Felice duality, therefore denying anyone an opportunity to resurrect them.

As we all now know, the great carbuncle was both a tracking device and transmitter given to Uncle Rogi by Marc/Unifex so that he could readily communicate with him, especially in times of trouble, and eventually call down the great intervention.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sentence in Magnificat that states that there is a dangerous red glass with a white flame inside buried under a hillside in Spain.  That is Felice and Culleket.  However, many times when Fury is present or discussed, there is a reference to the Roman Catholic candle in the room, a red glass with white flame. A hint from Julian??

I never associated the Great Carbuncle with the duality, it's not referred to has having a flame within.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this? Perhaps the exact quote of the sentence you mention; or some of the references.

Answer (score 1):

Unifex never did tell Rogi that Elizabeth died on Earth!!
In "Diamond Mask" at the start when Unifex & Rogi are in Keaku cave, he states that after their work on Duat had finished she was "tired and ready to pass on" and "begged him to follow her into the peace and light of the Cosmic All", implying she died in the Duat galaxy, not in the Milky Way - never mind on Earth.

The Carbuncle is a Lylmik artifact, as determined by Jack in "Magnificat" and used as the model for the device he constructed to put down Marc's rebellion.

There are many, many gaps (or unresolved storylines) which always led me to think we might get lucky and get a series detailing the Duat work along with Unifex' lonely sojourn in the early Milky Way (again, in the same section of "Diamond Mask" he tells Rogi "I made many ghastly mistakes" before the Lylmik evolved & he adopted their race as his own. The development of the early Galactic Milieu would have made a wonderful series.

Then there are all the unresolved items in the Pliocene saga - some of which are pointed out above (Agraynel's life from Morna-Ia's prophecy at her birth, Nodonn's Son, "Little Thagdal" (they obviously meet & marry from the inferences but why so disatrous?), but the Felice/Culluket Duality was never unresolved - just an oddity. Elizabeth's developing preseience states she knew it would never pose a threat to the Many-Coloured land again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Perhaps you could make it a little clearer how this answers the question of what happened to the Felice/Culluket duality?

Answer (score 0):

If the last statement is true about the "Great Carbuncle" not being the duality of Felice/Culleket, then it does leave a gap in the story. But in the Pliocene Saga after Felice fused with Culleket the stone was examined by Elizabeth (I think) and she stated that there existed a miniature Unity within. And in the Intervention Series Denis examined the Carbuncle and noticed something deep within. The Carbuncle was also used by Atoning Unifex (Marc) to initiate the Great Intervention. That indicates that it must be connected to the Unity somehow. Otherwise Unifex would have just reached out mentally with the signal.

The Carbuncle/duality could have been taken to Earth in the past by Elizabeth and Marc. She was the only one allowed in the Room Without Doors and Unifex told Rogi that Elizabeth died on Earth.

Comment: "The development of the early Galactic Milieu would have made a wonderful series." I could not agree more!!!